# Connect Micronaut with Hashicorp Vault

Tags: java, micronaut, hashicorp-vault

I need some help to configure Micronaut with Vault. I'm trying to load secrets from my local Vault on my application.yml properties from Micronaut.

I have downloaded the Vault CLI and started a dev server, and before that, I have configured a secret in the kv secret-engine with `vault kv put secret/application SECRET_GENERATOR_JWT=foobar`

For Micronaut, I'm reading the [official documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.3.2/guide/index.html#distributedConfigurationVault) to configure the connection with the Vault, but when I start the application locally, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.secret.SecretSignatureConfiguration] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.secret.SecretSignatureConfiguration]: Could not resolve placeholder ${SECRET_GENERATOR_JWT}
```

How can I solve this problem with Vault?

This is my **Micronaut's application.yml**

```yml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: hello
  config-client:
    enabled: true
  security:
    authentication: bearer
    token:
      jwt:
        signatures:
          secret:
            generator:
              secret: ${SECRET_GENERATOR_JWT}
vault:
  client:
    token: s.pkUenRJ2TCNOPYghsd5an0Iw
    uri: http://127.0.0.1:8200
    config:
      enabled: true
    secret-engine-name: secret
```

This is the **Maven's dependency** section:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-discovery-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And my **annotationProcessorPaths**:

```xml
<configuration>
  <annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
      <!-- must precede micronaut-inject-java -->
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </path>
    <path>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
      <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
    </path>
      <path>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-security-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${micronaut.security.version}</version>
    </path>
  </annotationProcessorPaths>
  <compilerArgs>
    <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=hello.world.cli.maven</arg>
    <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=hello-world-cli-maven</arg>
  </compilerArgs>
</configuration>
```

Micronaut version: 2.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you need to provide the environment variable or put a default value.

The first option is to set the variable environment like:

```
$ export SECRET_GENERATOR_JWT="superSecreteGeneratorJWT"
$ ./mvnw mn:run
```

the second option is configure your `application.yml` like this:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: hello
  config-client:
    enabled: true
  security:
    authentication: bearer
    token:
      jwt:
        signatures:
          secret:
            generator:
              secret: ${SECRET_GENERATOR_JWT:`superSecreteGeneratorJWT`}
```

in this way you will be setting your environment variable correctly.

Further info https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#propertySource

Then you have to inject it like:

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Value;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class YourServices {

    private final String secret;    
    YourServices(@Value("${micronaut.security.token.jwt.signatures.secret.generator.secret}") String secret) {
       this.secret = secret;
    }

}
```

More info: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#valueAnnotation

Comment: Hello jics, I tried both options that you have mentioned, but they didn't work as expected. I'm still getting problem with bean instantiation when I try to use the `@Value("${SECRET_GENERATOR_JWT}")` to validate if the solution has worked.

Comment: Ok. Now you have to follow this: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#valueAnnotation